About deregistration in Germany
I am a non-EU citizen and live in Germany. My rental contract in Germany expires on the 1st of September, and then I leave Germany. My German residence permit expires on the 30th of September. For some reason, I need it to be active for some time after leaving Germany: Switzerland, the country to which I enter, says that I may apply for a Swiss permit with the German permit (it would serve as an entry visa).
Could you please tell me if, in practice, it is possible just to deregister online after applying for the Swiss permit? The main issue that disturbs me is the absence of a formal registration place in Germany after the 1st of September. I am not entirely sure whether I can simply do nothing regarding this - not going to the citizen's office and saying that I am leaving the apartment. Then, from the point of view of the citizen's office, I would be formally registered at the old apartment, which may hypothetically cause some problems to my landlord, etc.
The point is that I have not even found how to make an appointment to notify the office that I am moving out of the apartment, only the appointment for registration at a new apartment. It looks to me that deregistration is formally not possible without registration. But what if, after moving out of the apartment, I, say, would like to stay at my friend's home for a few weeks or just go on vacation within or outside Germany? It looks like a gray zone where I may do whenever I want and, in particular, not say that I am outside of Germany already (say, I am on vacation).

Please try to separate your questions. The question seems to be around two issues: a) Moving out of an apartment and cancelling a lease contract and b) moving from Germany to Switzerland and getting a residence permit there. Is this right?

@PMF: No, the only true question is whether (in practice) I may deregister online one month after moving out of Germany; it is marked in bold. The rest are just possible issues that I see, but they may be irrelevant, depending on the true state of things.

In practice, what is important is that (1) the state knows where to send your official mail, and (2) that you leave the country when your residence permit expires. I wouldn't advice it but it is unlikely that something serious happens if you don't deregister before 30th Sep. There might be some issues if you are stopped by police and don't actually live at your registered permanent residence anymore. But that's mostly because of your residence permit.

No, in most municipalities you can not deregister online (yet [1]) and one month after moving out is too late. See for example the helpful information provided by the city of Hamburg: https://www.hamburg.de/behoerdenfinder/info/11404965/n0/
To summarize:
You can only deregister if (either):

You move out and don't have a permanent residence in Germany.
You move out of your secondary residence.
You stay abroad for more than one year.

The latter is relevant for German citizens. If your residence permit expires, you can (and should) also deregister, see point 1.
(Note that legally you always need to deregister if you move out of your permanent residence. Fortunately, registering at a new permanent residence serves also as deregistering at your old permanent residence if you move in Germany.)
You can deregister no sooner than 7 day before moving out and no later than 2 weeks after moving out (see §17 Bundesmeldegesetz).
You can deregister in person or in written form (e.g., by postal mail, but usually still not online). In the latter case you need to provide the deregistration form and a copy of your ID or passport.
You deregister at the Meldebehörde, i.e., the same office where you have registered.

[1] You can check there : https://verwaltung.bund.de/leistungsverzeichnis/de/leistung/99115005070000
